# What is the relationship between the angular speed and the diameter of the eye of a water vortex?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity, vortex

In a water vortex formed in a plastic bottle, what is the relationship between the angular speed of the water and the diameter of the hole in the cap? I would have expected that according to the conservation of angular momentum, the smaller the hole the faster the water speed (L = r x p).
However, I've been trying to test this relationship out but seem to get that the larger the hole the faster the water goes.

Comment: I think the shape of the bottle matters too.

Comment: Cant remember the details but look into kolmogorov length scale.
This is the scale in which eddies in the water (micro-turbulence) dissipate...

Comment: I can't say 'don't look at Kolmogorov' (it's interesting), but it's not exactly applicable here (not turbulent.  Conservation of $L$ sounds right. To hold it constant $r$ and $p$ must vary inversely.  The issue here might be that the larger hole permits a higher total flow rate causing faster transfer from potential to kinetic energy.

Comment: What angular speed are you talking about?  Can you be more precise about what you are asking?